# Retrieve Incoming Parameters in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm posting some parameters to a remote URL in my Rails4 application, from /orders/:id route with show controller method.

The parameters sent to a service from my application and the service is returning a bunch of parameters to my applications' /fail or /success pages depending on if the response is successful or not. I can see the incoming params from the logs.

I would like to create an OrderTransaction with this parameters in my Order controller, how can I do this?

```
orders_controller.rb

  def success
    ### I would like to create an OrderTransaction here with the incoming parameters!
    @transaction = OrderTransaction.new(????????)
  end

  def fail
    ### I would like to create an OrderTransaction here with the incoming parameters!
    @transaction = OrderTransaction.new(????????)
  end
```

**incoming parameters in logs =>**

```
Started POST "/orders/fail" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-01 13:40:28 +0300
Processing by OrdersController#fail as HTML
Parameters: 
  {
    "TRANID"=>"", 
    "type"=>"Auth", 
    "refreshtime"=>"5", 
    "lang"=>"tr", 
    "amount"=>"30", 
    "ACQBIN"=>"490740", 
    "clientIp"=>"193.140.28.145", 
    "name"=>"AKBANK", 
    "cardHolderName"=>"dsadas dasdsa", 
    "okUrl"=>"http://localhost:3000/orders/success",
    "failUrl"=>"http://localhost:3000/orders/fail",
    "storetype"=>"3d_pay_hosting",
    "Response"=>"Declined"
    ....
  }
```

**order.rb =>**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :participation
  has_one :transaction, :class_name => "OrderTransaction"
end
```

**order_transaction.rb =>**

```
class OrderTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

**routes.rb =>**

```
post 'orders/success' => 'orders#success'
post 'orders/fail' => 'orders#fail'
resources :orders, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show]
```

**orders_controller.rb =>**

```
require 'digest/sha1'

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  def show
    @hashing = {
      clientid: POS['clientid'],
      oid: Time.now.to_i.to_s,
      amount: @order.participation.examination.exam_fees.first.fee.to_s,
      okUrl: POS['okUrl'],
      failUrl: POS['failUrl'],
      islemtipi:POS['islemtipi'],
      taksit: '',
      rnd: Time.now.to_i.to_s,
    }
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        ...
      else
        ...
      end
    end
  end

  def success
    ### I would like to create an OrderTransaction here with the incoming parameters!
    @transaction = OrderTransaction.new(????????)
  end

  def fail
    ### I would like to create an OrderTransaction here with the incoming parameters!
    @transaction = OrderTransaction.new(????????)
  end

  private

  def set_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:id, :user_id, :participation_id, :amount, :cardHolderName)
  end
end
```

**orders/show.html.erb=>**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order, html:{class: "well"}, :url => "https://testsanalpos.est.com.tr/servlet/est3Dgate", :method => :post) do |f| %>
  <% @hashing.each do |k, v| %>
    <%= f.input k, input_html: {name: k, value: v}, as: :hidden %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Approve" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You will be able to get them from the params hash as you would in any other rails request.  `OrderTransaction.new(amount: params[:amount])` e.t.c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
#app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
def success
   Orders.new(order_params)
end

private

def order_params
    params.permit(:client_ip, :etc, :etc)
end
```

--

This will use the conventional [`strong_params`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) pattern in Rails, which will only whitelist the params you require. This should work okay considering your `params hash` is populated with the data from your remote service